# How can I solve this trigonometric equation system?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

[image]
As the picture shows,there are four equations and three angles,\theta1,\theta2,\theta3. I need to solve the values of this three angles. If the range of the angles needed, then consider (-Pi,Pi). BTW, I know the results:"\theta1=\theta2=Pi/8".
My codes are as follows.

```
C1 = Sqrt[2/3.];
C2 = Sqrt[1/6];
C3 = C2;
C4 = 0;
Solve[Simplify[{Cos[t1] Cos[t2] Cos[t3] + Sin[t1] Sin[t2] Sin[t3] == 
C1, Cos[t1] Cos[t2] Sin[t3] - Sin[t1] Sin[t2] Cos[t3] == C3, 
Cos[t1] Sin[t2] Cos[t3] + Sin[t1] Cos[t2] Sin[t3] == C4}], {t1, t2,
t3}]
```

Comment: Well, _Mathematica_ presents 16 numerical solutions to me. If you prefer more general, symbolic solutions (there seem to be infinitely many) then just remove the decimal dot  in `C1 = Sqrt[2/3.]`. (In _Mathematica_, occurence of inprecise numbers use to kick off numercal routines instead of symbolic ones.)

Comment: Oh, I just realized that your code lacks the second equation. After adding it, _Mathematica_ returns solution _only_ if you remove the decimal dot. Which appears to me like a bug.

Comment: When I write all four equations, the command 'Solve' doesn't seem to work. And it seems that I can't get a result if I use symbolic calculation.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" What does that mean? What exactly does `Solve` return? In my case, it returns lengthy expressions containing `ConditionalExpression`, but it does work. I am working with version 12.0, though. Maybe you are using an older version?

Comment: Well, I use the version 10.1. It just returns '{}'.

Comment: Hm. That is not supposed to happen. Either the new version is wrong about its solutions or version 10.1 should return a message à la "not solvable with this method"...

Comment: This is yet another situation where employing the Weierstrass substitution is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Try (with Version 11.0)

```
C1 = Sqrt[2/3];
C2 = Sqrt[1/6];
C3 = C2;
C4 = 0;
rel = TrigReduce[{Cos[t1] Cos[t2] Cos[t3] + Sin[t1] Sin[t2] Sin[t3] == C1, Cos[t1] Cos[t2] Sin[t3] - Sin[t1] Sin[t2] Cos[t3] == C3, Cos[t1] Sin[t2] Cos[t3] + Sin[t1] Cos[t2] Sin[t3] == C4}]
Solve[rel, {t1, t2, t3}]
```

Comment: Thank you first,but I get a bunch of ConditionalExpression results.

Comment: Those conditions are due to the periodicity of results. If you are interested in one precise solution you can make **Solve[rel, {t1, t2, t3}]/.{C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> 0}** and voilá!